# C undeclared(first use in this function) error

Tags: c, interrupt-handling

I am writing a C program on NIOS II SBT for Eclplise to deal with Pushbuttons interrupts on a DE2 board, not that it matters but I keep running into this error 'keys_irq' undeclared(first use in this function) error. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
volatile int keys_edge_capture;
static void keys_int_init() {
    void* keys_edge_capture_ptr = (void*) &keys_edge_capture;
    // Enable all three keys as interrupt
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_IRQ_MASK(PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE, 0x0F);
    // Reset edge capture register
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_EDGE_CAP(PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE, 0x00);
    // Register ISR and place it on the interrupt table
    alt_ic_isr_register(PUSH_BUTTONS_IRQ_INTERRUPT_CONTROLLER_ID, PUSH_BUTTONS_IRQ,keys_irq, keys_edge_capture_ptr, 0x00);
}
void keys_irq(void* context) {
    // Recast context to keys_edge_capture type
    volatile int* keys_edge_capture_ptr = (volatile int*) context;
    // Read the edge capture to determine what triggered the interrupt
    *keys_edge_capture_ptr = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_EDGE_CAP(PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE);

    if (*keys_edge_capture_ptr & 0b0100) // extract KEY2
        *(red_leds) = *(switches);
    else if (*keys_edge_capture_ptr & 0b1000) { // extract KEY3
       //do something
    }

    // clear the edge capture register
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_EDGE_CAP(PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE, 0x00);

    // dummy instruction to synchronize the handler

    IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_EDGE_CAP(PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE);
    return;
}

int main()
{

    int SW_Value,Keys_Val;
    int mask = 0xF;


    while(1){
        SW_Value = *(switches) & mask;
        *(green_leds) = SW_Value;
         keys_int_init();
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is unclear with the error message? The name is used in thus statement alt_ic_isr_register(PUSH_BUTTONS_IRQ_INTERRUPT_CONTROLLER_ID, PUSH_BUTTONS_IRQ,keys_irq, keys_edge_capture_ptr, 0x00); but not yet declared.

Comment: C requires you to declare functions before you call them. So either add a prototype for the function at the beginning of the file, or reorder the function definitions.

Comment: It appears keys_irq is a function in your program. It needs to be prototyped before its use. Since it is an interrupt service routine it may not need to be that would depend on what the compiler is expecting. The compiler I utilize uses `#int_####` before the function to tell the compile it is a specific interrupt. I would look at the manual for your compile to see how it is handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `keys_int_init` is calling a reference to `keys_irq`. Since `keys_irq` is not yet defined, the compiler doesn't know what the function is.  In order to avoid this, you can add something called a *prototype* at the beginning of the file, before `keys_int_init` is defined.

```
void keys_irq(void* context);
```

This tells the compiler what type the function is so it knows how to handle it.

Comment: The `keys_irq` within the `alt_ic_isr_register` function call of the `keys_int_init` function definition is not the same as the `keys_irq` function definition. The former is either a variable or macro defined elsewhere.